# Running Junit Test on Class that gets input from file , but Scanner and BufferedReader objects lead to stack overflow error in the tests

Tags: java, junit, java.util.scanner, stack-overflow, fileinputstream

[image]I am running `JUnit` tests on a method `checkFile()`, the method is supposed to check a file for some values and prompt the user when the values in the file are not permissible for a new file. If the file is ok, the method returns a value.

**The problem is** my test fails due to a StackOverflow error each time and never actually runs. The **error points** to the `scanner object` I am using to access the file.

I think the issue may be related to my use of recursion in the method but I cannot think of any other way to do this without writing redundant code if I don't use recursion.

Fyi, I know I could break this method into smaller methods but this assignment requires that I do not create any additional methods. **I have tried** to use `BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader(file))`
also but the same issue occurs.

Fyi , line 137 in the  Simulator class is where I instantiate the object Scanner Reader = new Scanner(file);

```java
public ArrayList<Customer> checkFile(int stops, File file) {
        Simulator sim = new Simulator();
        int linesProcessed = 0;
        String customerdata = " ";
        String[] dataArray;
        int[] parsedVals = new int[4];
        String delimiter = " ";
        List<Customer> custList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        List idArray = new ArrayList();

        try {

        Scanner Reader =new Scanner(file);//--> this appears to be causing the issue. 

        while (Reader.hasNextLine()) {

            customerdata = Reader.nextLine();
            dataArray = customerdata.split(delimiter);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
                try {
                    parsedVals[i] = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[i]);
                     if (parsedVals[i] <=0 ){

                       System.out.println("file input 0");
                       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                     }

                     if (i==2 | i==3   ){
                       if(parsedVals[i]>stops){
                         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                       } 
                     }

                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    if (linesProcessed == 0) {

                        System.out.println("Each line must have four integers. Try again.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(" Regular:Data in input file is not correct. Try again.");
                    }
                   sim.getInputFile();
                   sim.checkFile(stops, file);
                }
                catch(IllegalArgumentException args){

                  System.out.println("Data in input file is not correct. Try again.");
                  file =sim.getInputFile();
                  custList = sim.checkFile(stops, file);
                }
            }

            try{

                 if(parsedVals[2]==parsedVals[3]) {
                   throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                 }

                 custList.add(new Customer(parsedVals[0], parsedVals[1], parsedVals[2], parsedVals[3]));
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){

              System.out.println("Data in input file is not correct. Try again.");
              file =sim.getInputFile();
              custList = sim.checkFile(stops, file); 
            }

            idArray.add(linesProcessed, parsedVals[0]);
            linesProcessed++;            
        }

        boolean duplicates = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < idArray.size(); j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < idArray.size(); k++) {
                if (k != j && idArray.get(k) == idArray.get(j)) {
                    duplicates = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (duplicates) {
            System.out.println(" Duplicates: Data in input file is not correct. Try again.");

            File newfile = sim.getInputFile();
            sim.checkFile(stops, newfile);
        }
        }
           catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            System.out.println("File not found, try again.");
            file = sim.getInputFile();
            sim.checkFile(stops, file);
        } 
        return custList;
}
```

There are many tests but all the tests essentially do something similar. See bellow :

[image: Img]

Comment: Where is outContent defined?

Comment: and what is the actual error?

Comment: Splitting this method into several smaller ones is a good idea here. Have you tried reading the file using classes from `java.nio`?

Comment: //create local variables for streams
 private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                                                                                          
 private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

Comment: @AndyNope  @ Stultuske  I have added more information to the post

Comment: @deHaar I cannot use java.nio or split the method , I have to follow the design document that was provide to me . the method is written as described in the doc

Comment: @deHaar , I just checked it out but I am not familiar with  it , how would you use it to solve this problem  if I may ask ?  ( code example if possible)

Comment: You can receive a `List<String>` representing the lines of the file by `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("y:\our\path\to\the\fi.le"))`, which loads the entire file into the RAM or, for bigger files, you can stream the lines by `Files.lines(Path path)`. Both results are directly iterable.

Comment: @deHaar Thanks , I will try that  and update. I still would like to get to the bottom of why I am getting this error  if possible. Another favorable result would be  finding a way to make the test ignore this error and actually do whats suppose to do .

Comment: I wouldn't try to ignore a `StackOverflowError`, it is not ignorable. How often do you call that method? Are there many instances of `Scanner` around the same time during your tests?

Comment: The test  calls getInputFile() which uses scanner , it calls checkfile right after which also uses scanner  , checkfile calls getinputfile and itself again if the file contains bad data so that the user can be prompted to try a different file . I can use a loop for that but it becomes very cumbersome and the method grows even larger

Comment: @deHaar it’s also worth noting that the code runs fine with no errors

Comment: Maybe, you haven't closed the `Scanner`, which may cause a resource leak. Have you applied `Reader.close()` anywhere before the `return` statement? If not, do so and run the tests again.

Comment: Will try closing the reader and update @deHaar

Comment: I reread the doc and it said I should return null if the data in the file was not acceptable . Given this new information I just used a while loop to rerun  checkFile() each time the return value was null. Doing that instead of using recursion solved the problem .  It does appear that the issue was partially with the open file stream however but the code is working now so I moved on. Thanks @deHaar

Comment: @SteveBien-Aime Nice, good luck then…